# Loop through string array and change label text

Tags: c#, arrays, string, winforms, foreach

I have a string array which are the questions of a quiz and want to loop through them so that user can answer questions and move onto the next.

When I run the label text is blank and the error is that cannot convert `string` to `int`, so I'm quite confused.

```
string[] questions = new string[4];

questions[0] = "A";
questions[1] = "B";
questions[2] = "C";
questions[3] = "D";

foreach(string x in questions)
{
    lbl1.Text = questions[x];               
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't even compiles... an array index can't be a string...

Comment: I doubt you can even run it, it has compilation errors.

Comment: After you fix the error you will be surprised when only the last string will be shown in your label (You will never be able to see the label change its text while looping)

Comment: Consider programming in Python if you want to use strings as indexes.

Comment: Also, the `foreach` loop won't what you think it will - it'll result in the last item being in the text box, so this is exactly the same as simply assigning `D`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, x is referring to the string value, not an index in the list.  Try this:

```
lbl1.Text = x;
```

Comment: How did this answer get 5 votes in 13 minutes?

Comment: Because 5 people agreed the answer is useful...? @tomredfern

Comment: Oo it works! Thank you!

Comment: @A.King No problem! Also, if you wouldn't mind marking this as answer for others to know this has been resolved that'd be great. Just click the arrow underneath the vote buttons to mark it as answer.

Comment: @Yahtzee rather than answering such an obviously off-topic question, please vote to close it instead.